# Seemingly seperate objects interfere with eachother during initialization

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, reference

I'm 100% sure this is my fault. And I bet it's something really obvious. So believe me when I say I've looked over my code for a while before posting.
I just need some help from someone to find the cause of these errors, and I'm sure I'll be able to solve it from there. Maybe just a fresh pair of eyes looking over the code is enough to spot the error quickly.

Using python 3.9

## The problem

The first time I create a Command object, all the outputs seem fine.
But if I create a second Command object, the output of the first Command object change.

If I for example run this:

```
test_command = Command("Power to comms", {REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES["power"]: Power(value=1)},
                               {REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES["comms"]: Comms(value=2)})
```

I get the following output i the debugger:

```
Power to comms [Command]
    Input resources: {'Power': <data_structure.Power object at 0x7f17e56e78b0>}
    Output resources: {'Comms': <data_structure.Comms object at 0x7f17e56e77c0>}
```

But if I afterwards run this:

```
test_command2 = Command("Comms and power to navs", {REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES["comms"]: Comms(value=2),
                                                            REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES["power"]: Power(value=1)},
                                {REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES["navs"]: Navs(value=5)})
```

I get the following output in the debugger:

```
Power to comms [Command]
    Input resources: {'Power': <data_structure.Power object at 0x7f17e57135b0>, 'Comms': <data_structure.Comms object at 0x7f17e5713610>}
    Output resources: {'Comms': <data_structure.Comms object at 0x7f17e56e77c0>, 'Navs': <data_structure.Navs object at 0x7f17e56e78b0>}

Comms and power to navs [Command]
    Input resources: {'Power': <data_structure.Power object at 0x7f17e57135b0>, 'Comms': <data_structure.Comms object at 0x7f17e5713610>}
    Output resources: {'Comms': <data_structure.Comms object at 0x7f17e56e77c0>, 'Navs': <data_structure.Navs object at 0x7f17e56e78b0>}
```

First of all, we can see that the Power object in both Command objects share the same address. This is not what I have intended. So that's the first error.
Secondly, why does the first command suddenly have more input/output resources than before?

I've included the relevant code below:

## My code

```
class Command:
    """
    Contains a ratio for exchanging input resources into output resources
    """

    name: str
    input_resources: dict[str, type(Resource)] = {}
    output_resources: dict[str, type(Resource)] = {}

    def __init__(self, name: str,
                 input_resources: dict[str, type(Resource)], output_resources: dict[str, type(Resource)]):

        self.name: str = name

        for input_resource_name, input_resource in input_resources.items():
            self.input_resources[input_resource_name]: type(Resource) = input_resource.copy()

        for output_resource_name, output_resource in output_resources.items():
            self.output_resources[output_resource_name]: type(Resource) = output_resource.copy()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        output: str = self.name + " [Command]" + "\n\t" \
                      + "Input resources: " + str(self.input_resources) + "\n\t" \
                      + "Output resources: " + str(self.output_resources) + "\n"
        return remove_trailing_newlines(output)

    def copy(self) -> type(__name__):
        input_resources_copy: dict[str, type(Resource)] = {}
        for input_resource_name, input_resource in self.input_resources.items():
            input_resources_copy[input_resource_name]: type(Resource) = input_resource.copy()

        output_resources_copy: dict[str, type(Resource)] = {}
        for output_resource_name, output_resource in self.output_resources.items():
            output_resources_copy[output_resource_name]: type(Resource) = output_resource.copy()

        return Command(self.name, input_resources_copy, output_resources_copy)
```

```
class Resource:
    """
    The base class for all resource types, such as Comms, Navs, Data, Heat, Drift, Thrust
    """

    name: str
    value: int
    min_value: int
    max_value: int

    def __init__(self, name: str, value: int = 0, min_value: int = 0, max_value: int = 999):
        self.name: str = name
        self.value: int = value
        self.min_value: int = min_value
        self.max_value: int = max_value

    def is_valid_value(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the numerical validity of the resource value based on init parameters
        """
        return self.min_value <= self.value <= self.max_value
```

```
class Power(Resource):
    """
    This subclass of Resource, contains variables and methods specific to this particular in-game resource.
    This is what's considered a regular resource.
    """
    def __init__(self, value: int = 0):
        super().__init__(REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES["power"], value=value)

    def next_turn(self) -> bool:
        return self.is_valid_value()

    def is_valid_end_of_route(self) -> bool:
        return self.is_valid_value()

    def copy(self) -> type(__name__):
        return Power(value=self.value)
```

The other resources like Comms, Navs, Data, are exactly the same as the Power class, except for the name.

And the following is instantiated in the global scope:

```
REGULAR_RESOURCE_NAMES = {
    "comms": "Comms",
    "navs": "Navs",
    "data": "Data",
    "power": "Power"
}
```

Comment: BTW, `dict[str, type(Resource)]` is not a correct type annotation, what do you mean by `type(Resource)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I use type(Resource) because the expected type is a subclass of Resource. If I didn't use type(), the IDE would complain when I pass in a subclass of Resource.

Comment: Yeah, that is *totally incorrect*. It is not even a valid type annotation. You probably just want `Resource`, and even if you could use use an expression like `type(Resource)` in an annotation (it isn't valid), then `type(Resource)` evaluates to `type`, which is *clearly* not what you want

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok I see. It seemed to work because the IDE didn't complain, and it gave me all the correct suggestions as a result. But I checked what type() does and I agree with you, it's not entirely correct.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So I would need an alternative. How would you go about typehinting a base class in such a way that it will also expect subclasses of that base class?

Comment: Just the base class, `Resource`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's not sufficient. I had already tried that. Otherwise I wouldn't have had any reason to use type().

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga When I don't use type(Resource) to typehint its subclasses, I don't get autocompletion for the subclass methods and properties. But when I do use type(Resource), these autocompletions work flawlessly. I don't know if maybe you could refer me to a PEP spec that shows type([insert base class]) is "totally incorrect"? It seems JetBrains, the developers behind my IDE, doesn't think its that bad of a syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define variables for a class like this

```py
class Command:
    """
    Contains a ratio for exchanging input resources into output resources
    """

    name: str
    input_resources: dict[str, type(Resource)] = {}
    output_resources: dict[str, type(Resource)] = {}
```

these variables are assigned to the *class* rather than an instance. In your `__init__` function, you assign to the class's variable rather than a variable owned by the instance. If you remove the class level definitions, and initialize these separately in the `__init__` as Frank mentions below, it should work.

Comment: Just to be slightly clearly, you need to get rid of the two `= {}` above and then add to your `__init__` function, 'self.input_resources = {}` and `self.output_resources = {}`

Comment: Yup. @rchome solved it! Thank you :)